# VSCode autocomplete / Intellisense - Properties at the bottom

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VSCode's autocomplete is driving me insane.

I can't find any options to ensure properties are at the top of the autocomplete list when I press cmd-space.

[image]

Are there any recent guides or extensions for how to set up vscode code autocomplete / intellisense to be tolerable for react, js, ts devs?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Fixed by changing Snippet Suggestions setting.

You can find that in Settings > Text Editor > Suggestions. Make sure 'top' is not selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the recent activity on this post, I'm going to update with my current config that is much less infuriating.

This table of [**Types of Completions**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) helped me figure out that I can disable `keywords`

And also my snippet suggestions is set to `inline`